# SQL & C# - I have a query that is giving me all the details I want but i am not sure how to get a Total Price

Tags: c#, sql

Below is my code and the output I get from it. I get the correct output but I need to calculate the total price and I am not sure how to go about it.

Any help is much appreciated

```
// Search Database
if (query.Any()) 
{
    int carID = query.FirstOrDefault().Id;
    string carRegg = query.FirstOrDefault().regNo;
    string carMake = query.FirstOrDefault().Make;
    string carModel = query.FirstOrDefault().Model;
    int hourS = query1.FirstOrDefault().Hours;
    DateTime dateS = query1.FirstOrDefault().Date;

    var test = (from a in dbC.Cars
                where a.Id == carID
                join b in dbC.Services on a.Id equals b.CarId
                join c in dbC.PartsUseds on b.ServiceWrkNo equals c.ServiceServiceWrkNo
                join d in dbC.Parts on c.PartsPartNo equals d.PartNo
                where a.Id == carID && b.Date == ((from b1 in dbC.Services where b1.CarId == b.CarId select b1.Date).Max())
                select new
                       {
                           serviceNum = b.ServiceWrkNo,
                           date = b.Date,
                           PartNo = c.PartsUsedNo,
                           replacedParts = d.PartName,
                           priceP = d.Price,
                           hourS = b.Hours
                       }).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");
    Console.WriteLine("CAR SERVICE DETAILS: \t\t " + carMake + " " + carModel);
    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - " + "\n");

    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");
    Console.WriteLine("LAST SERVICE TOOK PLACE ON:\t " + dateS.ToShortDateString());
    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - " + "\n");

    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");
    Console.WriteLine("HOURS SPENT ON THE SERVICE:\t " + hourS);
    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - " + "\n");

    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");
    Console.WriteLine("PARTS USED:   \t\t\tPRICE      PART");
    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - " + "\n");

    foreach (var item in test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t        " + item.priceP + "\t   " + item.replacedParts);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - " + "\n");
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Z2S.png)

Comment: `test.Sum(x => x.priceP)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `test` is a `List` that contains all the elements that you want to sum, you can use Linq to calculate the total like this:

```
var total = test.Sum(x => x.priceP);
```

In Addition to that I would introduce a temporary variable for those calls:

```
int carID = query.FirstOrDefault().Id;
string carRegg = query.FirstOrDefault().regNo;
string carMake = query.FirstOrDefault().Make;
string carModel = query.FirstOrDefault().Model;
int hourS = query1.FirstOrDefault().Hours;
DateTime dateS = query1.FirstOrDefault().Date;
```

like this:

```
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
int carID = result.Id;
string carRegg = result.regNo;
string carMake = result.Make;
string carModel = result.Model;
int hourS = result.Hours;
DateTime dateS = result.Date;
```

This should improve performance because you prevent multiple database calls which could have happened before